# Grafana elasticsearch - How to do arithmetic operation on two elastic queries result

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am drawing timeline link chart to get avg post counts per active users. I have following query result:
A: total active users [unique] count per hour
B. total posts added by all users per hour
I want to draw line chart for avg posts per active users for that hour [B/A].

How I can divide result of B by A for each hour.
[image: Refer screenshot for two line charts for A & B I want to draw another line for B/A]

Comment: I am able to get those avg directly from elasticsearch, it means it is supported by elasticsearch.
Below is sample query:
http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=78e0e615ee343d35dd617edfa6c63e64

I am not sure, How I can achieve the same in Grafana.

Comment: try this plugin: https://github.com/GoshPosh/grafana-meta-queries

Comment: meta queries is not working in Grafana v6.4.2